# Shapes don't appear to be reacting to setting ZIndex?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently, I have three different types of objects that I draw to the screen (I'm using a ZoomableCanvas, if that makes a difference): beacons (concentric blue circles), tables (black rectangles), and debugRectangles (gold rectangles.  The objects are displayed/layered on the Z-axis according to the order in which they're added to the ItemSource, but it's not always possible for me to add shapes in Z-ordering.

[image] This image shows how it looks, depending on the order of objects being added.  I'd like for the shapes to respect the `Panel.ZIndex`es I've set, and in doing so, look like the top image (except with the gold rectangle in the back).

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <!-- Gold rectangles drawn here (color set in code) -->
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="rectangle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding fill}" Stroke="{Binding border}" StrokeThickness="5"
                                   Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" Panel.ZIndex="-1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding i}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>

    <!-- Black rectangles drawn here -->
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="tableBlock">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding fill}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"
                                   Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" Panel.ZIndex="50"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding i}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>

    <!-- Blue circles drawn here -->
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="beacon">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="DodgerBlue" Width="{Binding outerRadius}" Height="{Binding outerRadius}" Panel.ZIndex="97"/>
                        <Ellipse Fill="SkyBlue" Width="{Binding innerRadius}" Height="{Binding innerRadius}" Panel.ZIndex="98"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="99"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Within a template, they follow the order (I can rearrange the components of a beacon), but relative to each other, no dice.  Can anyone identify the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZoomableCanvas` relies upon `Panel` to render, which means it uses the standard ordering for `ZIndex`.

```
<Window x:Class="ZoomableApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <ZoomableCanvas>
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="250" Width="250" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="200" Width="400" Panel.ZIndex="2" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="400" Width="200" />
        </ZoomableCanvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: Red rectangle on top of blue, with green on the bottom]

The problem you are having is that your visual tree looks like this:

- `ZoomableCanvas`

  - `Grid`

    - `Ellipse` with `Panel.ZIndex="98"`

Since `Ellipse` is a child of Grid, the `ZOrder` doesn't affect the `ZoomableCanvas`, but instead sets the `ZIndex` of the `Ellipse` relative to the other children of the grid.  In order to change the layering of the `ZoomableCanvas`, you need to set the `ZOrder` property on the child of the `ZoomableCanvas` – the `Grid`:

- `ZoomableCanvas`

  - `Grid` **with `Panel.ZIndex="98"`**

    - `Ellipse`

Example:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Panel.ZIndex="100">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding fill}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"
                            Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" Panel.ZIndex="50"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding i}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you are using a `ListBox`, you end up with additional levels in your tree:

- `ZoomableCanvas`

  - `ListBoxItem` with `ItemContainerStyle` setting `Panel.ZIndex="98"`

    - `Grid`

      - `Ellipse`

Example of use:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="98" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

If you have multiple varying `ZIndex`es, you could expose a property on the data item and bind to that, or use a [`ItemContainerStyleSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the logic in code-behind.

You can also use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to look at the created tree to identify these sorts of issues.

Comment: Nothing.  I've put my complete XAML in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DU9cPmEN.  Does the fact that I'm using the ZoomableCanvas within a ListBox (as it was in the ZoomableCanvas2 example program) affect anything?

Comment: @Benjin, yes.  Using it in a `listbox` means the child of `ZoomableCanvas` is `ListBoxItem`, not your item.  See the update for how to fix.

Comment: Whoops; thought I had.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Panel.ZIndex on the Grids?

Comment: No dice.  It didn't autocomplete the ZIndex property, so I had my doubts.  Set it to -1, and it didn't work.